# Function with a neutral fixed point such that nearby points spiral away

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am looking for a function with a neutral fixed point, such that when you take a point near it and find its orbit, its cobweb diagram spirals away from it. Any ideas?

Comment: Let's try to force the fixed point to be the origin. Then, you'll to need $f(x) = -x + ?(x)$. The function $?(x)$ should satisfy $?'(0)=0$ and it should have the same sign as $-x$. It would help to have an experimental tool there's one [right here](https://marksmath.org/visualization/cobwebs/) if you'd like to play with it.

Comment: I've been trying that with Mathematica, but I can't get anything to work out

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The function $$f(x) = -x-x^3$$ works.